# PHP Judy installation on Windows

Tags: php, windows, judy-array

I'm new to php and I'd like to use Judy Arrays on windows and I'm having troubles with installation.

I followed steps on page http://php.net/manual/en/judy.installation.php and I get to the step where I've got "Judy.lib" file but I don't know what to do next. It says

> "copy this into the php-sdk library folder and name it "libJudy.lib"
>   Then copy the include file "judy.h into the php-sdk includes folder."

but I have no idea what "php-sdk library and includes folder" is

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are for building from source code.

If you don't want to compile from source you can try downloading a precompiled DLL from [the PECL page for the PHP Judy extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/judy), drop it in your `PHP\ext\` folder, and enable it in the appropriate `php.ini` file.

This process is [documented in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php) and [referenced in the installation instructions for the PHP Judy module](http://php.net/manual/en/judy.installation.php) that you mentioned in your question.

Unfortunately, it looks like [precompiled DLLs for the latest version of PHP Judy are only available for PHP 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, and 5.6](http://pecl.php.net/package/Judy/1.0.2/windows).

Comment: Ok, so I droped `php_judy.dll` to `PHP\ext\ ` folder and added line `extension=php_judy.dll` to `php.ini`. And when I try to create Judy array it throws **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Judy' not found**

Comment: Does the Judy class show up in the output of `phpinfo()` or `php -i`? Does your version of PHP match the PHP Judy DLL you downloaded?

Comment: Oh, versions don't match, now I understand why you wrote that last paragraph. So I can't use php 5.6+ if I want to use Judy?

Comment: @Hoostee, I see a precompiled DLL for PHP 5.6, but if you want to use it with PHP 7+ you'll have to try compiling it from source (as you were originally doing). It's a lot more work, and since the Judy library hasn't seen a new release since late 2013 there's no guarantee it will build against PHP 7+, but you can try.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks for the answers.